# Fetching browser log via Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, browser

I'm trying to catch all messages via Selenium WebDriver (console.log, error, info and warn), but I'm getting only error messages. Using `logPrefs.enable`(`LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL`); with `LogEntries.class`

[image]

But I'm getting only error-level messages.

(Edit: adding some code)

```
LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);

public LogEntries(Iterable<LogEntry> entries) {
    List<LogEntry> mutableEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (LogEntry entry : entries) {
      mutableEntries.add(entry);
    }
    this.entries = Collections.unmodifiableList(mutableEntries);
  }

logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);

Object[] logString = DriverInfraNG.getBrowserConsole(getDriver());
```

Comment: As such, I doubt anybody can answer. Please edit question and add some more context. Maybe some small code snippet demonstrating the problem ?

Comment: added snippets, hope this would help.

Comment: I don't know how to get the full log, but I know how to call a JS function using Selenium and get the return value of that function, if that would help you I can answer

Comment: Well, that can be a workaround till I'll find normal solution (to return array of strings). Can you share your function ?